# How to find out location / path of current active desktop background image (Ubuntu 18.04, GNOME)?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, desktop-background

I've set up custom desktop background image some time ago, and now I can't remember where it's located in my system. I really like the image, and want to know how to output image location so I can save it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Launch Terminal and run the following command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

This should show you the full path to the picture currently set as desktop background.

Comment: What if i use dynamic wallpapers? This command gives me `'file:////home/itsme/Images/ng-wallpaps/background.xml'`.

Comment: @brownian Check the `xml` file, it should contain path to all the wallpaper images.

Comment: yes, i know, i'd like to know which particular image placed on the wall at the moment. Let's say there are hundreds of images and i have to get programmatically which one is being displayed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104478/how-to-get-wallpaper-file-name-if-using-dynamic-wallpapers

Comment: This doesn't work. The `file://` path given points to an image, but it is *not* the current wallpaper. The other links here in the comments lead to other dead end answers and aren't helpful.