# How to get wallpaper file name if using dynamic wallpapers?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, 18.10, desktop-background

I have a hundreds of images in some folder and use `xmlback` script to generate `background.xml` file and set it as a wallpaper.

So, now:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
'file:////home/itsme/Images/ng-wallpaps/background.xml'
```

How can I get current image file name (or position inside xml file), exaclty?

It does not depend of `xmlback`, however, with one of packaged dynamic backgrounds i have this result:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/contest/cosmic.xml'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xmllint` with the `--xpath` setting to extract relevant parts of an XML document:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(/background/static/file)' /usr/share/backgrounds/contest/cosmic.xml
```

Comment: This gives me *the first* image file name, instead of displayed currently.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah for that I couldn't find anything in the gnome source code that says it would save that https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-desktop/blob/4c56c96b3f1c368ca3737cb7ff476a6bb037ae51/libgnome-desktop/gnome-bg.c#L55